# SQL Bulkcopy using DATA Access block

Tags: c#

I am using the below piece of code for SQL Bulk copy

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConString))
{
con.Open();
SqlBulkCopy sqlBC = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
sqlBC.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable";
sqlBC.WriteToServer(dtOppConSummary);
}
```

Can anyone provide me the equvalent code using Data access block Enterprise library

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a bulk copy pattern out of the box with the DAAB. The `SqlBulkCopy` class does not implement any interfaces besides disposable.

If you want to use bulk copy in a DAAB environment, you will have to modify your DAAB implementation to include it. Some steps you'll have to take are:

1. Create an `IDbBulkCopy interface
2. Create a wrapper class that implements the `IDbBulkCopy interface and wraps SqlBulkCopy
3. If you need access Oracle, implement the `IDbBulkCopy interface to use ADO.NET's "Array Binding" feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's going to be possible because the point of the data access block is to abstract you away from a specific data source. SqlBulkCopy if specific to the SqlClient libraries, and I don't think there's a generic way of doing this kind of operation across other data sources.

Comment: Ok can i replace the sql connection object with data access block??

Comment: or this is the best way to handle this??

Comment: I guess I should have asked why you are keen to try and use the data access block anyway...

I'm not sure that you want to be using the data access block for this - you're using a SQL Server specific feature, so any benefit of going through the data access block is gone...

Comment: actually other my other code i have converted to DAAB and this is the only piece of code left and hence i had posted this query